# How to create an in-memory database with schema based on an existing file database

Tags: c++, c, sqlite, database-schema

I have an existing database which structure is used accross the whole application. Instances of the databases are periodically rotated. I have a database file `template.sqlite` which is used as a template for all newly created databases. I want to use it, not a creation script, so that I have to maintain only one file, the empty database template itself.

I would like to create an in-memory database with the same structure based on that template file.

I know I can open the database and read it's structure, then create the database manually in memory. If possible, I would like to be able to do it in a more automatic way.

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `.dump` command of the [command-line shell](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html) do create a bunch of SQL commands that you can execute.

Alternatively, you can use the [backup API](http://www.sqlite.org/backup.html) to copy the template into a new database.

Comment: Dumping the script is what I would like to avaid. I would then have to maintain the script and update it with schema change. The backup API, though, seems to be exactly what I need!

Comment: @Dariusz: note that the generation of the script could be automated as part of the build process.

Comment: @MatthieuM. yes it could, but setting it up is more work than just reading the db which already exists with the few lines of code below. Besides, it would depend on another tool which has to be present on the system which is making the build, which in turn is another unnecessary dependancy.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick solution for all seeking answer to this question: a bit of `C` code that does the trick:

```
int loadOrSaveDb(sqlite3 *pInMemory, const char *zFilename){
  int rc;
  sqlite3 *pFile;           /* Database connection opened on zFilename */
  sqlite3_backup *pBackup;  /* Backup object used to copy data */

  rc = sqlite3_open(zFilename, &pFile);
  if( rc==SQLITE_OK ) {

    pBackup = sqlite3_backup_init(pInMemory, "main", pFile, "main");
    if( pBackup ){
      (void)sqlite3_backup_step(pBackup, -1);
      (void)sqlite3_backup_finish(pBackup);
    }
    rc = sqlite3_errcode(pTo);
  }

  (void)sqlite3_close(pFile);
  return rc;
}
```